# String not showing the right result or parameter when function is called in PHP

Tags: php

When I run locally:

```
function sayHello($name) { 
    echo 'Hello $name';
}

sayHello('Lucas');
```

what I get in the browser is `Hello $name`. I know `"Hello " . $name;` will do but I am just curious because it is working fine for the guy on youtube, it is showing the right result for him.

I am running PHP 7.1 in MAMP and MacOS.

Comment: @John Conde, I didn't know what the problem was. If you don't know the difference how can you ask the right question? Thanks

Comment: That's why we have the duplicate questions. So we only have to explain it once and can point users to it whenever they have the same issue but didn't know what to ask.